# Add text in the corner of a button Android

Tags: android, button, layout, text

I have a quick symbol bar with a few buttons. I want to place a symbol in each corner of the button in addition to the button text. My goal is that when the user press the button then drag his finger in one of the corner direction, the symbol in the corner is inserted, like in Quoda app. Here's a quick sketch:
[image]

How can I write in the corners of the button programmatically?

For the second part, I guess I could do it this way: I calculate the x,y difference from the center of the button at the release then insert the right symbol.

EDIT: I cannot use a ImageButton and a drawable background, because I want the symbols to be customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create custom [compound component](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) based on `RelativeLayout` with `ImageView's` (You can also use `VectorDrawable's`) in center and corners like in [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#exercise-create-a-compound-view) tutorial.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps me can you explain further please

Comment: At first You can read [this](http://lucasr.org/2014/05/12/custom-layouts-on-android/) or watch [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rmGLws2eIQ) video. Or simple just add `RelativeLayout` and 5 `ImageView's` or even `TextViews` on it with corresponding gravity/alignment.(e.g. centerInParent="true" for symbol "=" and so on)

Comment: Actually I will only use a RelativeLayout with TextViews. I don't need it to be a button because I can set onClickListener on RelativeLayout